# CSS3 transform scale display judder

Tags: css, transform, scale

i've got following problem:
when im using transform scale for hover the image shows judder.

Here my Code:

```
<div class="item">
</div>

.item {
    background: transparent url("http://s14.directupload.net/images/141019/s3r8avxj.jpg") no-repeat 0 0 / 176px 176px; 
    width: 176px;
    height: 176px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: Arial;
    margin: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
    border: 5px solid #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); 
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

.item:hover {
    transform: scale(1.05);
    border: 5px solid #fff;
    cursor: default;
}
```

Fullscreen view: http://jsfiddle.net/excsa15w/embedded/result/

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/excsa15w/

Is there a possibility to remove the judding?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Change property

```
background: transparent url("http://s14.directupload.net/images/141019/s3r8avxj.jpg") no-repeat 0 0 / 176px 176px;
```

**To**

```
background: transparent url("http://s14.directupload.net/images/141019/s3r8avxj.jpg") no-repeat;
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/03qf3tcp/)

Comment: If you want want to fit background with container resize your source image

Comment: it still judding with your solution! The Image "jump" when hover quick in the left top corner for ca. 1 px and back.... this i dont want

Comment: Ok, think it is a Firefox problem. Try to open your jsfiddle with Firefox, you'll see what i mean.

Comment: with my solution i think it is not a problem

Comment: its still the same but just in firefox (v33.0)